# mbeanExporter Invocation of init method failed UnableToRegisterMBeanException… is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: spring, servlets, websphere, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am getting "mbeanExporter Invocation of init method failed UnableToRegisterMBeanException… InstanceAlreadyExistsException" while trying to start a very simple Spring Batch Admin application in Websphere 8. The entire application can be downloaded from https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-batch-admin-tutorial/.

This is a very simple Spring Batch Admin project with only one very simple job. I can successfully debug the project in Eclipse and I can build the war, deploy it to Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5 successfuly. By success I mean I can open the Spring Batch Admin console and trigger the job properly.

The error below I am getting only when I move such war to Mainframe Websphere 8.5 ND. I don't think it is direct related to mainframe/unix. In fact, I am wondering if it is not a conflict between the libraries described below in my Pom.xml and Websphere. Any idea what to check will be extremely appreciatted. Recently, I have certain issue when using Hibernate/JPA and by simply downgrade a bit the version fix the error. It was a bit similar scenario: works in Websphere Liberty Profile but didn't work in Websphere 8.5 ND until I downgrade the hibernate version in my pom.xml. Well, this time there is no hibernate at all but I typed here what fixed sometime ago and maybe it can help someone to give me some idea what to check. I have a scratch idea that it is library conflict but I don't know what to check or investigate.

I saw few people getting similar error by using Spring Boot but that isn't my case at all. Specially in [Getting exception while refreshing Spring ApplicationContext in Spring Boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499942/getting-exception-while-refreshing-spring-applicationcontext-in-spring-boot-appl) someone got exactly same error as me after added

```
@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport(registration = RegistrationPolicy.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

Nevertheless, I don't have any anotation in such project and I am not using EnableIntegrationMBeanExport at least explicitly. Maybe it is been used behind the scene but I am not that expert on it so if someone can give me possibilities to check it will be an excellent north. Additionally, I am not using Spring MVC.

Error when startuping the application

```
Trace: 2016/09/09 22:49:17.049 02 t=9BDE88 c=UNK key=P8 tag= (13007004)

  SourceId: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.logServletError

  ExtendedMessage: BBOO0220E: SRVE0293E: ÝServlet Error¨-ÝBatch Servlet¨: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: E

rror creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.U

nableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean Ýorg.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter@4ed60bcf¨

with key 'integrationMBeanExporter'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:cell=dt

l85cel,name=integrationMBeanExporter,type=IntegrationMBeanExporter,node=wlemyAppa,process=WLEmyApp

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.j

ava:1553)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.jav

a:539)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:

475)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:70

3)

at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:7

60)

...

at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanSe

at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:814)

at com.ibm.ws390.management.connector.corba.CorbaConnectorImpl.invoke(CorbaCon

at com.ibm.ws390.management.connector.corba._CorbaConnectorImplBase._invoke(_C

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.invoke(CommonBridge.java:1898)

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.getAndProcessWork(CommonBridge.java:725)

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.runApplicationThread(CommonBridge.java:614)

at com.ibm.ws390.management.connector.corba.CorbaConnectorImpl.invoke(CorbaCon

at com.ibm.ws390.management.connector.corba._CorbaConnectorImplBase._invoke(_C

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.invoke(CommonBridge.java:1898)

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.getAndProcessWork(CommonBridge.java:725)

at com.ibm.ws390.orb.CommonBridge.runApplicationThread(CommonBridge.java:614)

at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$ZOSWorker.run(ThreadPool.java:2116)

Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean Ýorg.springframework.integration.

monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter@4ed60bcf¨ with key 'integrationMBeanExporter';nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlready

ExistsException: spring.application:cell=mycel,name=integrationMBeanExporter,type=IntegrationMBeanExporter,node=wlemyAppa,process=

WLEmyApp
```

pom.xml

```
              <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>

              <spring.batch.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>

              <spring.jdbc.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.jdbc.version>

              <hsql.version>1.8.0.7</hsql.version>

              <commons.version>1.4</commons.version>

              <spring.oxm.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.oxm.version>

              <spring.batch.admin>1.3.1.RELEASE</spring.batch.admin>

       </properties>

       <dependencies>

              <dependency>

                     <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>

                     <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>

                     <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>

              </dependency>



              <dependency>

                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

                     <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>

                     <version>${spring.version}</version>

              </dependency>

              <dependency>

                     <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>

                     <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>

                     <version>${hsql.version}</version>

              </dependency>

              <dependency>

                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

                     <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>

                     <version>${spring.jdbc.version}</version>

              </dependency>

              <dependency>

                     <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>

                     <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>

                     <version>${commons.version}</version>

              </dependency>

              <dependency>

                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>

                     <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>

                     <version>${spring.oxm.version}</version>

              </dependency>

              <dependency>

                     <groupId>junit</groupId>

                     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

                     <version>3.8.1</version>

                     <scope>test</scope>

              </dependency>

              <dependency>

                     <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>

                     <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>

                     <version>${spring.batch.admin}</version>

                     <exclusions>

                           <exclusion>

                                  <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>

                                  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>

                           </exclusion>

                     </exclusions>

              </dependency>

              <dependency>

                     <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>

                     <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-resources</artifactId>

                     <version>${spring.batch.admin}</version>

                     <exclusions>

                           <exclusion>

                                  <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>

                                  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>

                           </exclusion>

                     </exclusions>

              </dependency>



       </dependencies>

       <build>

              <finalName>SpringBatchAdmin</finalName>

              <plugins>

                     <plugin>

                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                           <version>2.2</version>

                           <configuration>

                                  <source>1.7</source>

                                  <target>1.7</target>

                           </configuration>

                     </plugin>

              </plugins>

       </build>

</project>
```

Job-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

       xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">





       <bean

              class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

              <property name="locations">

                     <list>

                           <value>classpath:batch-default.properties

                           </value>

                     </list>

              </property>

              <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />

              <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />

              <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />

       </bean>





       <job id="myjob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"

              restartable="true">

              <step id="myStep" allow-start-if-complete="true">

                     <tasklet>

                           <chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="itemWriter"

                                  commit-interval="1000" />

                     </tasklet>

              </step>

       </job>



       <bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">

              <!-- property name="resource" value="${INPUT_FILE_LOCATION}"></property-->

              <property name="resource" value="file:/C:/temp/sampleData.csv"></property>

              <property name="linesToSkip" value="1"></property>

              <property name="lineMapper">

                     <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

                           <property name="lineTokenizer">

                                  <bean

                                         class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">

                                         <!-- <property name="names" value="${INCOMING_COLUMN_MAPPING}"></property> -->

                                         <property name="names" value="firstName,lastName,city,id"></property>



                                  </bean>

                           </property>

                           <property name="fieldSetMapper">

                                  <bean

                                         class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">

                                         <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="userModel"></property>

                                  </bean>

                           </property>

                     </bean>

              </property>



       </bean>





       <bean id="itemWriter"

              class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">

              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

              <property name="sql" value="${INSERT_QUERY}">

              </property>

              <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">

                     <bean

                            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />

              </property>

       </bean>



       <bean id="userModel" class="com.javacodegeeks.example.util.UserModel"

              scope="prototype" />





</beans>
```

Contex-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"      

       xsi:schemaLocation="

              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd

              http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc

           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">



       <!-- using in-memory store for batch meta-data -->

       <bean id="jobRepository"

              class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">

              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

              <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />

              <property name="databaseType" value="hsql" />

       </bean>



       <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">

              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>     

       </bean>



       <bean id="jobLauncher"

              class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">

              <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />

       </bean>



       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"

              lazy-init="true" destroy-method="close">

              <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />

              <property name="url"

                     value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/main/resources/hsqldb/batchcore.db;shutdown=true;" />       

              <property name="username" value="sa" />

              <property name="password" value="" />

       </bean>


</beans>
```

[image: Project Tree]

**** Edited:

I am reading [Deploying two Spring batch applications in same cluster in a single Weblogic Domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613538/deploying-two-spring-batch-applications-in-same-cluster-in-a-single-weblogic-dom) which explain how to make two Spring Batch Admin run in Weblogic. 
I can see that the person was facing exactly same issue. After that I created another Spring Batch Admin and deployed to my local Websphere Liberty Profile then I got exact same error I was picking up in mainframe.

Firstly it made happy because I thought I finally found the problem and solution.

I fixed in my local websphere by adding /META-INF/spring/batch/override/jmx-context.xml with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xmlns:int-jmx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx/spring-integration-jmx.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">



    <int-jmx:mbean-export id="integrationMBeanExporter" default-domain="SpringBatchAdmin" server="mbeanServer" />

    <context:mbean-export default-domain="SpringBatchAdmin" server="mbeanServer" />

</beans>
```

Well that was great news untill I tried same approach in Websphere 8.5 ND running in mainframe. Exactly same issue remains there. Please, I am desparetly looking for anything else I can at least try.

Comment: There is an `InstanceAlreadyExistsException` in the stack trace. Could you check if another application running on the Mainframe WAS is also built on the Spring framework?

Comment: Yes, I am sure there are more than one Spring Web application and probably there is another Spring Batch Admin as well. Well, how can I fix it?

Comment: According to your update, your issue is now specific to WAS for z/OS. Do take a look at the IBM docs [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cspr_data_access_tran2.html) and see if that helps. :-)

Comment: XSurgent, do you know how to "register the JMX MBeans with the MBeanServer instance of the container manager in the application server" in Websphere ND? I am almost sure that the configuration must be the same for any Enterprise Container like Glasfish, Weblogig and TomCatE++. I mean, if you know how to "register the JMX MBeans with the MBeanServer instance" and you can answer me I will probably only need few adjustments to make the same in Websphere ND.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the specifics :-| . I have seen that error before, which is why I wanted to point you in that direction and see if it helped.

Comment: was here contains one cel with few nodes (one node for each department). There is one node exclusevely didicated to my team so I can tell you that I have deleted all applications inside of such node. So, in my Node I am sure there isn't other application. In fact, in my Node there is only one server with a simple Spring Batch Admin. Inside of in othe nodes there are several others applications that I don't know. I don't think they cause such issue because each server start with diferent jvm. If you think even an application from different node can affect other, please, let me know your opnion.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem.

I have virtual hosting on the same machine where spring integration was used. Once deployed the test system everything was Ok. After a while, I deployed the prod system and all went wrong.

I specified at Application.class the following:

@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport(defaultDomain = "${managed.domain}")

and in the application.properties file I defined managed.domain the name.

The solution I've found here:

[Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230584/spring-integration-unabletoregistermbeanexception-instancealreadyexistsexceptio)